# Shortcode's output to use as other shortcode's parameter

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm trying to pass Shortcode A's output as a parameter to shortcode B

```
[su_post field="post_date_gmt"post_id="173" filter=""] // Output 2018-07-22 12:06:35
[transform_date date='2018-07-22 12:06:35'] // Here i wanna pass the output of above shortcode, something like:


[transform_date date='[su_post field="post_date_gmt" default="" before="" after="" post_id="173" filter=""]']
```

But it's giving an error

> ERROR: : date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface,
>   boolean given in

Clearly this is not the right way to do it, How can i achieve the desired results?

Comment: why are you doing it as shortcodes and why 2 shortcodes?  Can you show the actual code for the shortcodes?  did you try without the single quotes on the third line?

Comment: The second shortcode would have to be coded in such a way that explicitly supported passing shortcodes as arguments. I doubt many do this because it's really stretching their purpose. They're not a programming language. If these are your shortcodes you should change your approach and create a single shortcode that does what you want.